# newlines are ignored in javascript for asp.net multiline textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a multi line textbox on asp.net form and i am calling following javascript function on past event.

New lines are ignored if i paste any data.

I don't know if it is to do with javascript function. I can see '/n' in inner text but somehow it is not being rendered properly. "hello\nworld" is being rendered "hello world"

```
function handlepaste(textbox, e, label, len) {
    var savedcontent = textbox.innerHTML;
    if (e && e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {// Webkit - get data from clipboard, put into editdiv, cleanup, then cancel event
        if (/text\/html/.test(e.clipboardData.types)) {
            textbox.innerHTML = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
        }
        else if (/text\/plain/.test(e.clipboardData.types)) {
            textbox.innerHTML = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        }
        else {
            textbox.innerHTML = "";
        }
        waitforpastedata(textbox, savedcontent);
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
    }
    else {// Everything else - empty editdiv and allow browser to paste content into it, then cleanup
        textbox.innerHTML = "";
        waitforpastedata(textbox, savedcontent, label, len);
        return true;
    }
}

function waitforpastedata(elem, savedcontent, label, len) {
    if (elem.childNodes && elem.childNodes.length > 0) {
        processpaste(elem, savedcontent, label, len);
    }
    else {
        that = {
            e: elem,
            s: savedcontent
        }
        that.callself = function () {
            waitforpastedata(that.e, that.s, label, len)
        }
        setTimeout(that.callself, 20);
    }
}

function processpaste(textbox, savedcontent, label, len) {
    pasteddata = textbox.innerHTML;

    if (savedcontent.length > 0) {
        textbox.innerHTML = savedcontent + pasteddata ;
    }

    if (pasteddata.length > len) {
        textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0, len);
        document.getElementById(label).className = "red-text";
        document.getElementById(label).innerHTML = 'You are trying to type too much information ';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(label).className = "grey-text";
        document.getElementById(label).innerHTML = textbox.value.length.toString() + ' of ' + len + ' chars';
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried textbox.innerHTML = savedcontent.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') + pasteddata.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'); but two new lines '<br><br>' are rendered in on new line '<br>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because HTML doesn't render new lines the way you're expecting. Try `<br>` instead.

Comment: I have tried textbox.innerHTML = savedcontent.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') + pasteddata.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'); but two new lines '<br><br>' are rendered in on new line '<br>'

Comment: When you change "Hello\nworld" to "Hello<br>world" does it render they way you expect? I don't trust your replace statements.

Comment: yes it does replace it to "Hello<br>world" but "Hello<br><br>world" is rendered as "Hello<br>world"